# Placing a label at a point

Tags: plotting

I am a rookie in the use of *Mathematica*. How do I place a label next to the point where two lines intersect?

```
q[x_] := Q - (7 Q x)/(4 L) + (3 Q x^2)/(4 L^2) /. {Q -> 1, L -> 1}
line1 = Line[{{0, Q/2}, {L/3, Q/2}}] /. {Q -> 1, L -> 1};
line2 = Line[{{L/3, 0}, {L/3, Q/2}}] /. {Q -> 1, L -> 1};
Show[
  Plot[q[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Directive[{Thick, Red, Dashed}], line1, line2}], 
    AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Posição na Barra], HoldForm[Carga]}, 
    PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Distribuição da Carga na Barra], 
    LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Add an `Inset` or `Text` containing the label in the `Epilog` for your plot. Specify the inset position using the coordinates of the intersection point, which you already know.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are, as you say, a rookie, you might be interested in how much your code can simplified.

```
With[{Q = 1, L = 1},
  q[x_] := Q - (7 Q x)/(4 L) + (3 Q x^2)/(4 L^2);
  line1 = Line[{{0, Q/2}, {L/3, Q/2}}]; 
  line2 = Line[{{L/3, 0}, {L/3, Q/2}}];
  pt = {L/3, Q/2}];

Plot[q[x], {x, 0, 1},
  Epilog ->
    {Directive[{Thick, Red, Dashed}], line1, line2,
     Black, PointSize[Large], Point[pt],
     Text[pt, Offset[{20, 10}, pt]]},
  AxesLabel -> {"Posição na Barra", "Carga"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Distribuição da Carga na Barra",
  LabelStyle -> Black]
```

[image: plot]

#### Notes

1. Using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) rather than multiple replacements has the advantage of being easier to write and less error prone (each additional replacement is another chance to mis-type a value). It is also faster in execution.
2. Unless you are using a version of *Mathematica* older than V6, you don't need `Show`.
3. `HoldForm` can be useful in building labels, but in your case simple text strings will work.
4. The label text can be placed using [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset.html), which works in printers points and is thus independent of the plot coordinate system.

Comment: a much more useful answer than mine. Offset is nice. +1. :)

Comment: @ubpdqn I hope to learn a lot on this site. I'm realizing that there are many professionals here

Comment: @m_goldberg In the Wolfram Documentation, the command text describes the following:
Text[expr,coords]
Because it was necessary to insert the command in this way?:
Text[pt, offset[{20, 10}, pt]]} 
As "@ubpdqn" managed by inserting this way:
Text[Framed["Label", Background -> White], {1/3, q[1/3]}, #]}

Comment: @m_goldberg I am referring to the use of the term offset

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho. I'm not sure what your comments are asking. There are many ways to specify the position (2nd arg) in `Text`, My using `Offset` is not necessary but rather a matter of convenience that simplifies the code in this particular case. I didn't want the label to fall right over the point, but to be shifted to the right and upward so that it stands clear of the point.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho sorry I missed this discussion. As I commented to m_golberg, his answer is much more instructive and I voted for it and am glad you accepted. The notes are very instructive. Good luck :)

Comment: @m_goldberg You perfectly understood my question. Only had not understood as "@ubpdqn" managed to position the text only with #. Forgive me also if I misunderstood because I'm Brazilian and not usually very write in English.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Text` in the `Epilog` of 2D plots. For example (using the given functions and lines. I have removed `Show` as I was unsure why it was required):

```
plots = Plot[q[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[{Thick, Red, Dashed}], line1, line2,
       Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{1/3, q[1/3]}], Black, 
       Dashing[0], 
       Text[Framed["Label", Background -> White], {1/3, q[1/3]}, #]}, 
     AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Posição na Barra], HoldForm[Carga]}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Column[{HoldForm[Distribuição da Carga na Barra], 
        Row[{"offset: ", #}]}], LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, 
     ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {Automatic, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
     1}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}};
Grid[Partition[plots, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: As I am beginner and receive answers that contains more information than I expected, it's fantastic. Thank you very much. I really want to learn this program ...

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho  you are welcome. There are many ways to do things in Mathematica. So  play and if you get stuck  ask a question here. You posted your code and explained what you wanted. I just showed you a few things. The best way to learn is play. If you get stuck then there are diverse creative users here. I have and continue to learn from them. Have fun! :)

Comment: You can also use `Inset` instead of `Text` if you want the label to be a more complicated graphical object, e.g., two lines of text using `Inset[Column[{"line one","line two"}],{x,y}]`.

Comment: I noticed that the term # is used both to offer the coordinates of the text in the same way as the string that is used in column.