# Placing labels at points using Show[plot, Graphics[...]]

Tags: plotting, labeling

How do I label a point that I add to a plot of some kind using `Show[plot,Graphics[...]]`, from the documentation I cannot find out the correct way. I would have thought that the following would work but it produces an error:

```
Show[RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 Labeled[Graphics[{Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}]}] , "a"]
 ]
```

(See also this closed question: [Placing a label at a point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116617/placing-a-label-at-a-point), which was judged off-topic even though it looks completely on-topic too me.)

Comment: `Show[RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], Graphics[{Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}], Black, Text["a", {1/6 - .1, 1/3}]}]]` or `RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}], Black, Text["a", {1/6 - .1, 1/3}]}]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, thanks! I think I consider that a full answer so you could put it as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because `Labeled` is not a `Graphics` primitive or directive. Some alternatives

**Using the Text primitive and Show**

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 Graphics[{Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}], Black, Text["a", {1/6 - .1, 1/3}]}]]
```

[image]

**Using Epilog**

```
RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}], Black, Text["a", {1/6 - .1, 1/3}]}]
```

The result is the same as using `Show`.

**Using ListPlot, Callout and Show**

```
Show[RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 ListPlot[Callout[{{1/6, 1/3}}, "a", Left], Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

With [Callout](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) there are many options for customizing the appearance.

Comment: In the first case, how is the position determined. Does {1/6 - .1, 1/3} give the middle or the left most point of the text and can this be changed? (I think it is the middle which makes position more difficult.)

Comment: @Kvothe I don't really understand your question. The coordinate of the point is `1/6, 1/3}`. In the code, the `x` position is reduced by `0.1` to ensure that the text does not overlap the point. If you want to adjust the offset based on the length/size/font of the text then you need to compute its bounding box. There are ways to do that e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2334/58370).

Comment: I was asking what the provided position  `{1/6 - .1, 1/3}` is used for and whether it can be changed. Logical possibilities would be the left beginning middle or end of the text. A simple test, i.e. just replace "a" with a longer text, shows that the provided position is used to set the middle of the text. I was wondering whether this can be changed. For example in your example it would be convenient if we could set the position of the end of the word. That way if we increased the length of the label it would still be positioned nicely and not intersect with the point and the line.

Comment: @Kvothe Ahh, yes there is a way. `Text` takes a position and optional offset. Check the documentation. E.g. `Show[RegionPlot[x > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[{1/6, 1/3}], Black, 
   Text["abcdefghijklmnopqr", {1/6 - .1, 1/3}, {1, 0}]}]]`

Comment: Thanks! (And sorry for accepting so late I must have forgotten last time. I didn't even notice it was my own question this time haha.)

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help, and thanks for accepting.